# How to fix a completely unresponsive MacBook Pro 2018 keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina

I have a 2018 Macbook Pro 13” with Touch Bar running MacOS Catalina. Today my keyboard suddenly stopped working after sleep. It simply would not output ANYTHING. I foolishly restarted my computer before even trying to look into some settings. After that I was unable to login, connect a bluetooth keyboard, nothing. I could not even hold the option key to boot into bootcamp. I’m simply in shock right now, as my MacBook really cost a ton and is extremely vital to my studies and hobbies.
Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Does using a USB keyboard and mouse work?

Comment: yes, they do. By now my theory is that the cables to the trackpad and keyboard may have come loose, broken, or just lost any connection to the motherboard. My system sometimes tells me that it does not detect andy input devices and prompts me to plug them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth taking it to the Apple Store. There have been hardware/manufacturing problems with recent MacBook keyboards, and if it is such a problem, then Apple should fix it free.

Apple currently has a "[Keyboard Service Program](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks)" for a range of laptops, including yours.